# want to pass data from one intent to 2nd and after dat pass into 3rd intent.1st to 2nd has been done bt 2nd to 3rd intent didnt work

Tags: android

```
holder.clientcase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("case add Button Clicked", "**********");
                final int user_id = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                Intent update_user = new Intent(activity,
                    ClientcaseDetailMain_Screen.class);
                update_user.putExtra("called", "update");
                update_user.putExtra("USER_ID", v.getTag().toString());
                activity.startActivity(update_user);

            }
            }); pass dis USER_ID into 2nd intent ClientcaseDetailMain_Screen..like
CLIENT_USER_ID = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID"));
add_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CLIENT_USER_ID = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID"));
        Intent add_user = new Intent(ClientcaseDetailMain_Screen.this,
            Add_Update_Clientcase.class);
        add_user.putExtra("CLIENT_USER_ID", CLIENT_USER_ID);
        add_user.putExtra("called", "add");
        add_user.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(add_user);
        }
    });
```

after dat i want use value of CLIENT_USER_ID into Add_Update_Clientcase.class...i did use like CLIENT_USER_IDnew = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("CLIENT_USER_ID")); but it is not worked in d last intent means get value of CLIENT_USER_ID is null...how to accessible here in Add_Update_Clientcase.class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don;t use:

```
CLIENT_USER_IDnew = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("CLIENT_USER_ID"));
```

Use:

```
CLIENT_USER_IDnew = getIntent().getIntExtra("CLIENT_USER_ID"),0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using

```
 Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("USER_ID"));
```

intead of

```
Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_ID"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making you task more complex, just try to put your things/objects/variables in a "Common Class" with public variables so that you would be able to access it at any instance.